# Timestamp give wrong time

Tags: android, time, timestamp

I want to get timestamp time :

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(time);
    Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

But it works wrong. When it was 20:50 it shows 11:50 AM
Whats wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the timezone correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It May because of your device `Time Zone`, So please check your `Time Zone(GMT+HH:MM)`